# Альтернативы .addClass() и .removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Являюсь новичком в деле JS-разработки. Опыт написания работоспособных программ был. На данный момент самым бросающимся в глаза недостатком моих скриптов является их **громоздкость**. Ниже опишу подробно в чём она заключается.

Допустим у меня есть такой код.

```
<ul class="ul">
    <li>recommended</li>
    <li>latest</li>
    <li>highlightes</li>
</ul>
```

Что требуется от JS и JQ? При нажатии на один из элементов списка, этот элемент списка меняет цвет; соответственно этим цветом может быть выделен только один элемент.

Что мне предлагает мой опыт? Во-первых, каждому элементу списка присвоить идентификатор. Во-вторых, одному из элементов присвоить класс (.active), а в стилях прописать его. Итого:

```
<style>
    .active {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<ul class="ul">
    <li class="active" id="li_1">recommended</li>
    <li id="li_2">latest</li>
    <li id="li_3">highlightes</li>
</ul>
```

Новичку на первый взгляд может показаться, что достаточно прописать цепочку методов для каждого идентификатора.

```
$("#li_1").click(function() {
    $("#li_1").addClass("active");
}

$("#li_2").click(function() {
    $("#li_2").addClass("active");
}

$("#li_3").click(function() {
    $("#li_3").addClass("active");
}
```

Конечно, корявенько, поскольку не оптимизировано. Но, как Вы уловили, код ещё не выполняет своё предназначение: он только добавляет класс, и не просто добавляет, а необратимо. То есть нажав на один элемент списка он станет красным, нажав на второй - красным станет и он, нажав на третий - все элементы списка покраснеют. Что на этот раз нам подскажет скудный опыт новичка? Верно, в каждой функции-кликанью прописать цепочку методов, убирающей класс .active у других идентификаторов. И код будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```
$("#li_1").click(function() {
    $("#li_1").addClass("active");
    $("#li_2").removeClass("active");
    $("#li_3").removeClass("active");
}

$("#li_2").click(function() {
    $("#li_2").addClass("active");
    $("#li_1").removeClass("active");
    $("#li_3").removeClass("active");
}

$("#li_3").click(function() {
    $("#li_3").addClass("active");
    $("#li_1").removeClass("active");
    $("#li_2").removeClass("active");
}
```

Как Вы, уважаемые эксперты, смогли заметить, код избыточно разбух. Именно это я в начале назвал **громоздкостью кода**. Пример выше - небольшая иллюстрация. Мне приходилось писать длинные полотна, где в списке не 3 элемента, где-то 6-7, а в тебе функции класс менять не только одному какому-то элементу странице, а нескольким. Такой скрипт занимал более 2 экранов пролистывания.

В общем мой вопрос в следующем. **Как можно сжать, оптимизировать скрипт, аналогичный продемонстрированному выше?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".ul > li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
  <li>recommended</li>
  <li>latest</li>
  <li>highlightes</li>
</ul>
```

Если повторное щелканье по подсвеченному элементу должно его отключать:

```js
$(".ul > li").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
  <li>recommended</li>
  <li>latest</li>
  <li>highlightes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а чего не `siblings`?

Comment: @teran действительно

Comment: @Igor, объясните, пожалуйста, какое предназначение this в этом скрипте? Массив всех li, вложенных в .ul ?

Comment: @Kniga нет. в обработчиках событий jQuery `this` - это DOM элемент, в котором произошло событие

Answer (score 0):

```
var ul = document.querySelector(".ul");
var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");
ul.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
  li.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.toggle('active',false);
  });
  evt.target.classList.toggle('active');
})
```